# php form action not reading php variable

Tags: php, html, forms

It is working when I use page name but not working when I am using page name in php variable.

```
<?php $action_page = "page2.php"; ?>
<form action="<?php $action_page; ?>" method="post">

</form>
```

Unable to get it where I am wrong.

Comment: `<?php echo $action_page ?>`

Comment: Im trying to understand why you dont keep the logic with the form at the top of the file rather than passing it elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to 'echo' that php variable.

```
<form action="<?php echo $action_page; ?>" method="post">

</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You missed something.You should echo your variable.

Your code with the required `echo`:

```
<?php $action_page = "page2.php"; ?>
<form action="<?php echo $action_page; ?>" method="post">

</form>
```

Without an echo you'll only get an error.

You can also leave PHP out of this. Just HTML works fine too:

```
<form action="page2.php" method="post">

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need add `echo` before the variable-

```
<?php $action_page = "page2.php"; ?>
<form action="<?php echo  $action_page ?>" method="post">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed `echo` the variable. So when you see the source you will find `action` attribute with none

Just echo your varibale.